# Jquery receive json message from PHP

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following jquery function that submits to an iframe. The message sent back from PHP is json. I can't figure out how can I receive this message in jquery so I can display it to the user.

```
function IframeSubmit(){
    // remove iframe if exists
    $('#hiddenIframe').remove();

    // change target attribute on form
    form.attr('target', 'hiddenIframe');

    // create and add iframe to page
    $('<iframe />', {
        name: 'hiddenIframe',
        id: 'hiddenIframe',
        style: 'display:none'
    }).appendTo('body');

    // on response from php file
    $('#hiddenIframe').load(function(){
        // process received message here ...
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: use ajax, echo a json object via php `json_encode( $string );`

Comment: The `.load()` method is intended to load html content into an element, not JSON. try [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead, and process the results in its callback.

Comment: Error: getJSON() is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#myform').submit(function(){
          $("#hiddenIframe").remove();    
          $('<iframe name="hiddenIframe" />').appendTo('body').attr({'id': 'hiddenIframe'});
          var Frame = $('#hiddenIframe');
          var newSrc = 'about:blank?nocache=' + Math.random(); //force new URL
          Frame.attr('src', newSrc); 
          var iframe = $('#hiddenIframe').load(function(){
              var response = iframe.contents().find('body').html();
              var txt = $.parseJSON(response);
              $('#message').append(txt.message);
              if(txt.error == false){
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '?myurl',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: {
                           //some data
                       },
                       success: function(data){
                           //some action
                       } 
                   });                                         
              }           
         });                                             
    });
});
```

the output in iframe is:

```
var response = iframe.contents().find('body').html();
var txt = $.parseJSON(response);
```

read response like: txt.error or txt.message

PHP part:

```
$this->message['error'] = true;
$this->message['message'] = "Problem!";

echo/print json_encode($this->message);
```