# Posting server response in Iframe

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe

MY intentions are to post the response in the Iframe, say i will send back a script from my server which should call a predefined java-script method defined in my form.

I am not sure how to do this and even after doing some going i am no able to find any solution.
I can not use Ajax as it will create same origin policy error for me. here is what i have done so far

```
<form:form action="${request.contextPath}/springSecurity/login" method="post" commandName="loginForm" target="ajax_login_pannel_IFrame">
```

and here is the corresponding IFrame

```
<iframe width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="ajax_login_pannel_IFrame" ></iframe>
```

Comment: See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094902/jquery-receive-json-message-from-php/11095303#11095303), could you help?

Comment: @AlexBall: Thanks but unfortunately i am not able to use Ajax and it will cause me same origin policy as my Login will go with HTTPS and my overlay can be in HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

This should do - http://jsfiddle.net/Wspbr/1/

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.write('response goes here');​
```

**edit:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourScript.jsp',
    success: function(data) {
        $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.write(data);​
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit how i will write the response coming from server? being very limited to JS knowledge.

Comment: You can use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method. See edited part of my answer.